# list comprehension and repeated inner reference

Tags: python, scope, list-comprehension, variable-assignment

I wanted to reformat a text based on recognition by a regex.

so i basically made

```
regex= re.compile("(group1)(group2)(group3)(group4)")
text_groups=regex.search(text).groups()
```

text_groups is a list with enclosed groups.
I wanted to change the order in a constant manner.
I know that I can do it with

```
reordered_groups=np.array(text_groups)[[1,3,0]
```

but that's not my problem.

In order to avoid the conversion to np.array that would be computationally inefficient as string are involved, I preferred to use a list comprehension, with the added advantage to be able to filter based on condition:

```
reordered_groups=[ text_groups[i] if text_groups[i] is not None else "" for i in [2, 4, 1, 5] ]
```

I think that text_groups[i] repeat is ugly, and probably inefficient if you consider using similar technique on large lists, because you will call the index twice. How can we avoid that while not using for loops, which are inefficient on their own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `or` - when `text_groups[i]` is `None`, `or` will return the right-side of the statement, so you could do:

```
reordered_groups = [text_groups[i] or '' for i in [2, 4, 1, 5]]
```

For example, the following:

```
text_groups = ['e', None, 'c', 'f', 'x', None]
reordered_groups = [text_groups[i] or '' for i in [2, 4, 1, 5]]
```

returns:

```
['c', 'x', '', '']
```

Comment: I corrected my mistake in the list comprehension about the conditional statement, but this is wonderful! I was not even aware this keyword had such properties. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5309300/asongtoruin In case the test would not be the called variable to be None, do you have an idea about how to proceed? (say if len was longer than 5 for example?). By the way, how do you know this pecular behavior of or, it is quite far from intended boolean comparison? Thanks

Comment: @AndoJurai I'm not certain what you mean, sorry. Can you provide an example?

Comment: With regards to the operator, it's about the way [Python deals with boolean operators](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)

Comment: if the list comprehension was reordered_groups=[ text_groups[i] if len(text_groups[i])>5 else "" for i in [2, 4, 1, 5] ]. That's trickier for me because I don't see how to use boolean operators here

Comment: Well, you can't get the `len` of a `None` element, so you've got a problem there if you still have `None` in your list.

Comment: OK thanks. I was more about the case None was not a possibility, looking for some generalization.